# How can I list the schemas on my server?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know all the databases running on my MySQL server so I can check which priveleges I need to assign for new users. How can I list the schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a query window or from the mysql prompt:

```
SHOW SCHEMAS;
```

This command "lists the databases on the MySQL server host." Keep in mind that the listing is limited to "...only those databases for which [the logged in user has] some kind of privilege, unless you have the global SHOW DATABASES privilege".

See "[`SHOW DATABASES` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-databases.html)" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW DATABASES` lists the databases on the MySQL server host. `SHOW SCHEMAS` is a synonym for `SHOW DATABASES`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html